# Cygwin reads bashrc but yet doesn't remember aliases

Tags: bash, cygwin, alias

I've tried to setup cygwin with aliases.

I've used the default `.bashrc` but uncomented the aliases for ls, la ... etc.

I've placed it under `C:\Users\Dimitar` which is my home directory, and added a line `$HOME/.bashrc` in `/etc/profile`.

when i type alias, or try to use one i get nothing.

I've added echo "LOADED" at the end of it, and i see loaded when i run cygwin, but still no aliases.

What is the problem and how an i fix it?

Comment: What happens if you try resourcing it and then trying the alias? `. C:\Users\Dimitar\.bashrc` and then `some_alias_you_defined`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're using .bashrc and that it's not commented out in `.bash_profile`:

```
# source the users bashrc if it exists
if [ -f "${HOME}/.bashrc" ] ; then
  source "${HOME}/.bashrc"
fi
```

If you want to use a separate alias file make sure the appropriate lines are uncommented in `.bashrc` and that you've specified the file you'd like to use. For example .bash_aliases is common.

```
# Some people use a different file for aliases
if [ -f "${HOME}/.bash_aliases" ]; then
  source "${HOME}/.bash_aliases"
fi
```

That should really be all you need. Sample syntax within the aliases file:

```
$ cat .bash_aliases
alias shelldir'=cd /cygdrive/c/Dropbox/Dev/Shell'
```

Comment: Oh, i needed to put source before $HOME/.bashrc

Comment: Cool. If my answer helped could you mark is at being the chosen answer?